# Biztalk Insert or Update in to database using the SQL bindings

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

I have a requirement where the data from one database has to be selected and inserted or updated in to the other database depending on the destination. I have used the DBBinding to select from the source.In the destination do I have to use stored procedure to do this or selecting Insert and Update in the DBBinding will work for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Insert or Update unless you have some complex requirement to do in stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Vikas, my requirement is like if the data is not existing in the database it has to insert otherwise it has to update. If I am selecting Insert and Update in the SQLBinding, it will give me 4 schemas right. Like Insert and InsertRespone,  Update and UpdateResponse. So my confusion is how will I map from source to destination. Can you please explain me.

Comment: It really depends on the design and the volume of messages your solution need to process. If you have an orchestration then you can design this whole process in there and either use insert or update based on if record exists. This solution requires multiple calls to database which is ok as good as volume is manageable and you have a need to process the data in BizTalk. in case of low volume scenario or you simply want to avoid orchestration, then you should create one stored procedure doing this. Both approach works you just need to use the best of both in your case.

Comment: Sorry Vikas I am little confused. I have an Orchestration, do I have to set two maps one for insert and other one for update.

Comment: yes, you also need to make a select call to see if record exists

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a stored procedure for this and perform an upsert within it. You could use a Composite Operation to send all the data across to SQL in one transaction or investigate using a Table Value Parameter so you can send multiple rows to the stored proc (depending on the number of rows!).

To do this you would need to create a **MAP** between your source data and the **Composite Schema**.

This way you are only concerened with the schema of the stored procedure and the Composite Schema.

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788136.aspx

HTH